# Orchard Custom Content Type isn't saving

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have created a custom content type called 'AccessFolder'. I can see it in the list of content types and can create a new one. When I create a new AccessFolder, I get my editor template that I created for it. After I enter the information and click save, I'm directed to a `Not Found` page however the indicator message tells me my AccessFolder was created successfully.

In the driver, I can see the model after it is bound using the `updater.TryUpdateModel`. The correct values are assigned to the model's properties.

It just never gets to the database.

**AccessFolderPart:**

```
public class AccessFolderPart : ContentPart<AccessFolderPartRecord>
{
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return Record.Name; }
        set { Record.Name = value; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<RoleRecord> DownloadRoles
    {
        get { return Record.DownloadRoles.Select(x => x.RoleRecord); }
    }
}
```

**AccessFolderPartRecord**

```
public class AccessFolderPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ContentAccessFolderRoleRecord> DownloadRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**Relevant Pieces of AccessFolderPartDriver**

```
    protected override DriverResult Editor(AccessFolderPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        var viewModel = new AccessFolderViewModel(part, _roleService.GetRoles());
        return ContentShape("Parts_AccessFolder_Edit", () =>
            shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: templateName, Model: viewModel, Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(AccessFolderPart part, Orchard.ContentManagement.IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {

        var viewModel = new AccessFolderViewModel { Part = part };
        updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel, Prefix, null, null);

        if (part.ContentItem.Id != 0)
        {
            _roleService.UpdateRolesForAccessFolder(part.ContentItem, part.DownloadRoles);
        }

        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);

    }
```

I've been stuck on this since Friday. I've created custom types before and never had any problems with it. I can't see what I've done wrong here.

**Update** - Added content Handler class

Here's the one line for the handler:

```
public class AccessFolderPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public AccessFolderPartHandler(IRepository<AccessFolderPartRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the storage filter inside a content handler?

Comment: @BrandonJoyce Yep, I already have that. I updated the question to reflect it.

Comment: without log file it is not possible to find the problem.please post log file here so we can help you out.

Comment: Have you tried delete the nhibernate mappings (App_Data\Sites\[sitename]\mappings.bin? I have had similar experiences where there are no errors but data is not persisted to DB when coding new records. After the mappings regenerate the data saves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are missing the proper mapping on your driver:

```
    if (updater.TryUpdateModel(viewModel, Prefix, null, null))
            {
               part.Name= viewModel.Name;

               if (part.ContentItem.Id != 0)
               {
                   _roleService.UpdateRolesForAccessFolder(part.ContentItem, part.DownloadRoles);
               }
            }
```